# Cloudflare flexible SSL and redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, cloudflare

I'm having some really annoying problems with my domain.

I have Cloudflare flexible SSL on my site, and it makes a https call, IF I type it myself ><
When I try to force https to be used on my site via a `.htaccess` file I get an internel server error.

I would like all visitors to my site to always be redirected to `https://www.example.com` even if they type `example.com` or `example.com/index.php` etc. + using https on the whole site.

I just can't find the solution to this, so I'm trying stack.

My DNS settings on Cloudflare is an A record that points `domain.com` to a IP
and a CNAME record that says `www.domain.com` is an alias of `domain.com`

I have no page rules added on Cloudflare atm.

```
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


Options -MultiViews


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however, this
    # header should be send only for HTML pages and not for the other resources
    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|tt[cf]|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|woff|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

  # Audio
    AddType audio/mp4                                   m4a f4a f4b
    AddType audio/ogg                                   oga ogg opus

  # Data interchange
    AddType application/json                            json map
    AddType application/ld+json                         jsonld

    AddType application/javascript                      js

  # Video
    AddType video/mp4                                   f4v f4p m4v mp4
    AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
    AddType video/webm                                  webm
    AddType video/x-flv                                 flv

  # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot


    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf


    AddType     image/svg+xml                           svgz
    AddEncoding gzip                                    svgz

  # Other
    AddType application/octet-stream                    safariextz
    AddType application/x-chrome-extension              crx
    AddType application/x-opera-extension               oex
    AddType application/x-web-app-manifest+json         webapp
    AddType application/x-xpinstall                     xpi
    AddType application/xml                             atom rdf rss xml
    AddType image/webp                                  webp
    AddType image/x-icon                                cur
    AddType text/cache-manifest                         appcache manifest
    AddType text/vtt                                    vtt
    AddType text/x-component                            htc
    AddType text/x-vcard                                vcf

</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset utf-8


<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .jsonld .rss .vtt .webapp .xml
</IfModule>


#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#     Options +FollowSymlinks
   # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#    RewriteEngine On
   # REDIRECT /folder/index.php to /folder/
#    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
#    RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://www.domain.dk/$1 [R=301,L]
#</IfModule>


#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#</IfModule>

#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
#    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
#    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "(^#.*#|\.(bak|config|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$">

    # Apache < 2.3
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </IfModule>

    # Apache ≥ 2.3
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>

</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#    RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.dk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                      application/javascript \
                                      application/json \
                                      application/ld+json \
                                      application/rss+xml \
                                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                      application/x-font-ttf \
                                      application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                      application/xhtml+xml \
                                      application/xml \
                                      font/opentype \
                                      image/svg+xml \
                                      image/x-icon \
                                      text/css \
                                      text/html \
                                      text/plain \
                                      text/x-component \
                                      text/xml
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None

#<IfModule mod_expires.c>

#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
#ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"

#</IfModule>
```

Comment: what errors are appearing in the error log? If you are recieving a 500 error it should be logged.

Comment: I'm trying this in my htaccess file.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^=on$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your htaccess. Also, can you advise if cloudflare rules have been enabled to handle static HTML or if you haven't configured them. As this will advise us on if cloudflare is handling the entire website itself or not. It does however look like an incorrect configuration in the htaccess file. So you will need to post the error that appears in your error log file (normally on /var/log/apache( or httpd)/error.log or error_log

Comment: I'm not so much into all this, I'm pretty new to apache, htaccess etc.

But some weird happens. I tried to make an htaccess file with just simple etag removel. Then I get the internel server error. Also if the document is empty. I'll edit my Q with the original htaccess and there is no cloudflare rules applied to the site. I have just activated cloudflare to handle all trafic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Also please check that you have an SSL version of your virtual directory enabled in your httpd.conf/apache.conf file.

How are you managing the domain name? Through a control panel or through command line? Which class of cloud flare are you using? Do you have your own SSL certificate installed on the server?

Comment: It does not work. I could not find any information about virtual directory in my apache2 folder. I don't use command line as of now(still a beginner). I don't use any class of cloudflare? I just made my DNS point to theirs and activated SSL flex for my pro account. I don't have my own SSL.

Comment: Sorry I meant by class, do you use free cloudflare, business ect.. Also, the error maybe the fact that when you force https its not being handled by cloudflare

Comment: I use pro :) They say I need to make a self signed SSL and upload it to unoeuro(my host) then I can use full SSL instead of flex SSL. The flex SSL may cause many redirect problems with my server and cloudflare, so it seems.

Comment: What type of app is it going to be? A commercial website? If so, it won't work. It's just as secure but signed by an untrusted site so everyone will get and SSL warning (which no one will every go onto)

Comment: I wouldn't think https is a major ranking factor. However if you want to use ssl I'd recommend buying an ssl certificate

Comment: @LiamSorsby: The visitors are never going to see his self-signed cert, only CloudFlare's. CF doesn't care if the cert is self-signed, so for "full SSL", this is a completely valid alternative.

Comment: @Zano cloudflare only provides SSL protection from the client to CF. If you have any serverside script that must be called by CF this is not protected against attack so you will need your own SSL Cert. So in a way if you just use CF's certificate you will end up with a potential hole in your security.

Comment: @LiamSorsby, I agree, and I haven't stated otherwise. My only point was that your claim that "everyone will get an SSL warning" is just not true.

Comment: @Zano a valid point taken. You are correct in what you are saying.

Answer (score 9):

As stated here On [Cloudflare Official Support Site](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-HTTPS-traffic-with-Flexible-SSL-and-Apache-)

[image: CloudFlare Force Https]

So I'll walk you through what I did, (*as of 16-JUN-2016*)

## Since a picture speaks a thousand words. See Below

[image: Easy Way to Force SSL Flexible on Cloudflare]

### And you are done. It should start redirecting to https outright.

Answer (score 8):

From CloudFlare's knowledge base.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com$1 [L]
```

See https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-HTTPS-traffic-with-Flexible-SSL-and-Apache-

Just did this myself, works like a charm.

Comment: Using this only wordpress work. If I try to open any other files except wordpress files they still shows redirect.
Like
/  is wordpress base URL
/myfolder/ I created a folder myself and placed some png file and opening the file shows redirect always.
If I turn On Development Mode it works. but when Development mode is off. It wont work. I have tried clearing cache to everything.
Finally leaving Cloudflare SSL. Its full of bugs!

Answer (score 1):

the .htaccess didn't work for me either (neither did creating a rule with force https option).
What worked is I created a rewrite rule on CloudFlare to rewrite from `http://yourdomain.com/*` to `https://yourdomain.com/$1` and that fixed the issues (it took about half an hour to kick in though).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:
@Victor Häggqvist's htaccess rules combines with @Mohd Abdul Mujib's page rules (with * also in beginning of rule, though).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com$1 [L]
------
http://*yourdomain.com/*
```

As per Cloudflare's manual, the protocol must be http in the above for it to work.

I added a pure html page to Cloudflare and got too many redirects, but the above helped. Now I will go and install Wordpress on the site.

These are the links I gathered for my journey, in case they are helpful to someone else, too.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-HTTPS-traffic-with-Flexible-SSL-and-Apache-

https://blog.cloudflare.com/flexible-ssl-wordpress-fixing-mixed-content-errors/

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201717894-Using-CloudFlare-and-WordPress-Five-Easy-First-Steps

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-